# If 米 can be used to refer to America as a country (USA), can it also refer to America as a continent?

Tags: kanji, loanwords

I am currently studying this Kanji. In addition to the original meaning of *rice*, it also has other meanings of *meter* (SI unit of length) and *America*. In English and my mother tongue Indonesian, "America/Amerika" can refer to two things: the continent, and the country (United States of America). I have seen 米's usage in books and TV news to refer to the USA, and I wonder if the Kanji 米 is also used to refer to the continent of America. Thank you!

Comment: Not exactly a duplicate, but the following should answer your question. https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/82745/45489

Comment: Note that in much of the Anglosphere North America and South America are considered two continents collectively called 'The Americas'

Answer (score 2):

There are a few words where the 米 kanji is used to mean "America" in the continental or regional sense, as opposed to the specific country of the United States of America:

- 北米【ほくべい】: North America
- 南米【なんべい】: South America
- 中米【ちゅうべい】: Central America
- 中南米【ちゅうなんべい】: Central and South America (sometimes erroneously used to refer to Latin America -- erroneous, because Mexico is in North America, and is generally not included in [Central America](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_America))
- 米州【べいしゅう】: the Americas -- North and South America collectively

Comment: Not sometimes but almost always in non-technical contexts.